# Formally showing $K_{n} \star f(\theta) \rightarrow f(\theta)$ uniformly in $(\theta)$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals, fourier-analysis

In the text "Real and Complex Integration Problems" I'm having trouble verifying my approach in proving the following conjecture in $(2.).$

$(0.)$

$(0.1)$

$$K_{n}(\theta) = \sum(1 - \frac{|j|}{n+1})e^{ij \theta}$$

$(1.)$

Show that for any continuous $2 \pi$ periodic function $f$ on $\mathbb{R}$ one has:
$$ K_{n} \star f(\theta) := \frac{1}{ 2 \pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} K_{n}(\theta - a)f(\theta)d \theta = \sum(1 - \frac{|j|}{n+1})e^{ij\theta}(\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{-ija}f(\alpha) d \alpha)e^{ij\theta}$$

$(2.)$
$ \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \,\, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, $Show that $K_{n} \star f(\theta)$ $\rightarrow f(\theta)$ uniformly in $\theta$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$

**Lemma:**

$K_{n}$  can be written in $(1.)$ due to the property of Convolution's as formally developed in $(3.)$,

$(3.)$

Given two $2 \pi$-periodic integrable functions $f$ and $g$ on $\mathbb{R}$, we define their convolution $f \star g$ on $[-\pi, \pi]$, by:

$$(f \star g)(x) = \frac{1}{2 \pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(y)g(x-y)dy$$

A change of variables on our recent result yields the following:
$$(f \star g)(x) = \frac{1}{2 \pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x-y)g(y)dy$$

So applying our recent developments we can formally verify the conjecture in $(1.)$ by first attacking the RHS side as follows:
$$\sum(1 - \frac{|j|}{n+1})e^{ij \theta} \star f(\theta) =\frac{1}{ 2 \pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} K_{n}(\theta - a)f(\theta)d \theta =  \sum(1 - \frac{|j|}{n+1})e^{ij \theta}(\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{-ija}f(\alpha) d \alpha)e^{ij\theta})$$.

Now I need a hint on how I could proceed to show uniform convergence. After doing some initial thoughts, one could start by performing the following

$$\lim_{}K_{n} \star f(\theta) = \lim_{}\frac{1}{ 2 \pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} K_{n}(\theta - a)f(\theta)d \theta = \lim_{}\sum(1 - \frac{|j|}{n+1})(\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{-ija}f(\alpha) d \alpha)e^{ij\theta}$$

Comment: What are the bounds of the sum index j

Comment: j goes from n to j?

Comment: No it would be this, sorry my internet went out $$K_{n}(\theta) = \sum_{j=-n}^{j=+n}(1 - \frac{|j|}{n+1})$$

Comment: Are you familiar with the Fejer Kernel?

Comment: Yes i'm familiar with the Fejer Kernel

Comment: The proof that the convolution of the kernel you provided above converges uniformly to f is the same as the proof for the fejer kernel. You need to show the family of functions of $K_n(\theta)$ is a family of good kernels. Good kernels have the property that the convolution converges to the function.

Comment: Ahh ok after doing a little bit of searching and reading I found some stuff here:http://www.math.jhu.edu/~qzhang/courses/2007Fall/443/12.pdf. So was my initial approach correct or does it need refinement. Also  can you recommend a book with challenging Fourier Analysis Problems.

Comment: Wait, your formula $K_n$ does not depend on theta, is there some term missing. Also, this is a good resource for your question, specifically theorem 2.6 http://math.uchicago.edu/~may/REU2012/REUPapers/Cuddy.pdf

Comment: Wait the $K_N$ you provided was supposed to be the Fejer kernel? It is either wrong, or you are misinterpreting the sum. The study of fourier series introduces differnt way in which sums can be done, for example the Fejer kernel comes from a type of averaged sum, called a Cesaro sum.

Comment: Looking back at the book I didn't define the sum properly in my post I made some typo's i'll have to reedit the post.

Comment: Well if all you were doing was studying the fejer kernel, and uniform convergence of it, the pdf I provided has the in depth treatment of the problem. If you need help understanding any parts of it, just post another question on here.

Comment: I have a good base understanding of it when I typed this up from my messy notebook I made some typo's and mistakes I'm sorry :-(

Comment: No worries, good luck on your studies.